# CSS - :not(kbd) bug (style is still applying to <kbd> tags)

Tags: html, css

#### Example:

```css
html *:not(kbd):not(textarea) {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
kbd {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<kbd>abc</kbd><br/>
<textarea>def</textarea><br/>
<p>ghi</p>
```

#### Bug:

As you can see that the style is applying to `<kbd>` and `<p>` but not `<textarea>`.

Is it a CSS bug or a browser problem or a CSS syntax error?
I am using Chrome 54.0.2840.99 (64-bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't set a property for an element, then it will get its default value from the user agent stylesheet.

In the case of the textarea, that is `user-select: text`.

In the case of the kbd element that is `user-select: inherit`.

`inherit` means that it copies the value from the parent element, in this example that is the body element.

Your selector `html *:not(kbd):not(textarea)` does match the body, so the body element has `user-select: none` and the kbd element inherits that.

You need to either:

- Explicitly set the value of `user-select` on the kbd element *or*
- Exclude the kbd element's *ancestors* from your selector

The former is probably the easier approach.

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
}
textarea,
kbd {
  user-select: text;
}
kbd {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<kbd>abc</kbd>
<br/>
<textarea>def</textarea>
<br/>
<p>ghi</p>
```

Comment: So the solution is adding one more css to `<kbd>` tag: `kbd { user-select: text; }`. EDIT: It is no need to add `* { user-select: none; } textarea, kbd { user-select: text; }`.

Answer (score 1):

CSS1 -> English: Every descendant of the html tag will hereby recieve a 3px solid green border, except kbd and textarea (they where bad children)

CSS2 -> English: kbd however will recieve a color of red (cause he was really bad!)

Then kbd and textarea never recieve a border, and kdb was coloured red for life, the end.

so conclusion your CSS rules worked you just have to use a more visual CSS rule for the example.

```css
html *:not(kbd):not(textarea) {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
kbd {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<kbd>abc</kbd><br/>
<textarea>def</textarea><br/>
<p>ghi</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the parent, in this case `body`, not `html`.

```css
body *:not(kbd):not(textarea) {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
kbd {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<kbd>abc</kbd><br/>
<textarea>def</textarea><br/>
<p>ghi</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your parent in place of `div.yourclass` to get it unselectable

```css
div.yourclass *:not(kbd):not(textarea) {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: red;
}
kbd {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="yourclass">
  <kbd>abc</kbd>
  <br/>
  <textarea>def</textarea>
  <br/>
  <p>ghi</p>
</div>
```